# JavaScript Object Literal Trailing "Dummy" Pair

Tags: javascript

When working with object literals in JavaScript, I find myself frequently generating syntax issues around the last label / value pair since it does not require the trailing comma. I insert a new value and inevitably forget the separating comma.

```
.draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    opacity: 0.50  // <- missing comma
    revert: true   // new pair
});
```

So for the sake of my sanity, would it be reasonable to always have a dummy pair at the end? This seems to work and now all inserted pairs get a trailing comma. Are there other conventions out there? Is the double quote brilliant or idiotic? Feedback please! Thanks.

```
.draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    opacity: 0.50,
    "": null       // dummy pair
});
```

Comment: When happens when you insert after the dummy pair then?

Comment: I would always maintain the dummy pair as the last pair. All "real" pairs get the trailing comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

This is simply silly.

What you want instead is using code quality tools like jslint and jshint. If you hook these into your pre-commit on your version control or your text editor safe mechanism then you'll never miss these errors.

Alternatively you can try writing your code isaacs style

```
var x = { containment: "parent"
        , opacity: 0.50
        , revert: true
        };
```

Comment: Isaacs would work, but all I know is - if I see code like this in a code review - I am going berserk...but that's just my idiosyncrasies ... :):)

Comment: @ZenMaster isaacs has an entire style guide, it's a weird style but it's interesting. As long as everyone _agrees_ and _confirms_ to style guide X then it doesn't really matter what X is.

Comment: Thanks guys... I don't care for isaacs styling. I will now stop my silliness.

Comment: @Raynos not to open a discussion on a answered question, but conformity is not the only important thing - readable code is just as important and isaacs, to me, is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty object and then fill it with data. This would avoid using commas and is consistent.

```
var obj = {};
obj.containment = parent;
obj.opacity = 0.50;
.draggable(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I work with associative arrays frequently, so I do not necessarily miss the last comma.  If its easy of use you are going for, check out Coffee Script.

Your code would look like this:

```
draggable
  foo:
    key: value
  bar:
    key: value
```

and compile into:

```
draggable({
  foo: {
    key: value
  },
  bar: {
    key: value
  }
});
```